# Docker shared volumes create and attach problem

Tags: docker, volume, shared

I've a question about docker shared volumes.
I know that if I run a container with -v option I create a volume that I can share to another container with --volumes-from:

```
docker run -d -v DataVolume1:/datavolume1 --name container1 image1:v1.0.0
docker run --name container2 --volumes-from container1 image2:v1.0.0
```

But I cannot understand the full behaviour of this. It seems like volume from container 1 is a master and the same volume in container 2 is a slave. So container 2 can write and container 1 read or only the opposite?

Why I cannot use -v option on all my container like that?

```
docker run -d -v DataVolume1:/datavolume1 --name container1 image1:v1.0.0
docker run -d -v DataVolume1:/datavolume1 --name container2 image2:v1.0.0
```

or create a volume with:

```
docker volume create --name DataVolume1
```

and then attach to the two container with:

```
docker run -d -v DataVolume1:/datavolume1 --name container1 image1:v1.0.0
docker run -d -v DataVolume1:/datavolume1 --name container2 image2:v1.0.0
```

Is there some trouble because each -v recreate the volume and cut the link with the previous container? Or something other?
Because with two "docker run -v" I could also specify different mounting path for the same volume, so if it work for me is better, but I never see anyone use this way so what's the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All of your latter examples (using `-v volumename:...` in multiple containers) should work fine, and in fact I’d recommend avoiding `--volumes-from` in favor of those more explicit forms.  Is there a specific problem you’re having?

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze, no I don't have any problem, but I've seen always --volumes-from and also the official documentation use it. I've read also many post about mounting path that don't include my solution. If there isn't issues I'll use it. Thanks!